# I'd like to obtain record between 2 dates , but Date column is in string format in db. Using linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to obtain the record between 2 particular dates (using linq query), but the Date column in the db is in string format and i can't change that from MSSQL. Is there a way to compare the date 'strings' . I tried Datetime.Parse(date_string) but it doesn't work in linq

Here is the code

```
            var entity =
                (from o in iDb.IN_STG_EOM_ORDERS.Select(s => new
                {
                    s.id,
                    s.PickTicketNumber,
                    s.OrderNumber,
                    s.OrderID,
                    s.OrderDate,
                    s.FirstName,
                    s.LastName,
                    s.OrderShippingAddress1,
                    s.OrderAmount,
                    s.OrderAmountShipping,
                    s.OrderAmountTotal,
                    s.OrderShippingStatus,
                    s.OrderGiftWrapping,
                    s.IsError,
                    s.OrderShippingStatusId,
                    s.OrderStatusId,
                    s.LastModifiedDate,
                    st = DateTime.Parse(s.OrderDate),
                }).Where(w => w.OrderShippingStatusId != 0 && w.OrderStatusId != "29" && w.OrderShippingStatusId < 200 && w.OrderShippingStatusId != null 
                w.st <= startDate && w.st < endDate   ).AsEnumerable()
```

where `s.orderDate` is string

Comment: *Don't* store the date as a string. Use the proper type, eg `date` in SQL Server. Using `string` to store dates or numbers is a serious bug, as serious as storing, eg numbers as strings.

Comment: Could you add the code that doesn't work?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes common practice is you shouldn't store it as a string, but I can't make any changes in the db , so have to work with string

Comment: It's not just standard practice. You won't be able to use indexes for range queries unless the format is sortable by date like `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Given the code you posted, it may be impossible to write a date range query, eg if `st` contains something like `04/07/2019` - that's a string, sorted as string, which means `13/01/1800` always comes *after* `04/07/2019`. If the field holds a sortable form, you only need `startDate.ToString()` to generate a string to filter.

Comment: you can try to add computed column that will return date parsed from your string-date-column. and then use this computed column in your query.

Comment: @DibbaButt Please refer to my answer. Did my solution work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

try this function  Convert.ToDateTime()

Comment: doesn't work  , gives and error
``` An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```

Comment: @DibbaButt you still havent posted what the format is. You want to compare *strings* anyway, not parse dates

Answer (score 0):

@Dibba Butt If you don't really want to change the datatype from string to datetime on the database level.
As a workaround you can first fetch the data and store it into a list (Might have to fetch all the data).

Then filter the yourList to obtain the result between the ranges by using DateTime.ParseExact. Refer to the sample code below.

```
var res = yourList.ToList().Where(a => DateTime.ParseExact(a.st,"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= startDate && DateTime.ParseExact(a.st,"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) => endDate).ToList();
```

**Note: Modifying your code to obtain solution. Use below code instead.**

```
    // The first List without datetime range filter.

        var entity =
                        (from o in iDb.IN_STG_EOM_ORDERS.Select(s => new
                        {
                            s.id,
                            s.PickTicketNumber,
                            s.OrderNumber,
                            s.OrderID,
                            s.OrderDate,
                            s.FirstName,
                            s.LastName,
                            s.OrderShippingAddress1,
                            s.OrderAmount,
                            s.OrderAmountShipping,
                            s.OrderAmountTotal,
                            s.OrderShippingStatus,
                            s.OrderGiftWrapping,
                            s.IsError,
                            s.OrderShippingStatusId,
                            s.OrderStatusId,
                            s.LastModifiedDate,
                            s.OrderDate,
                        }).Where(w => w.OrderShippingStatusId != 0 && w.OrderStatusId != "29" && w.OrderShippingStatusId < 200 && w.OrderShippingStatusId != null).ToList();

// Now applying the filter.

var res = entity.Where(a => DateTime.ParseExact(a.OrderDate,"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= startDate && DateTime.ParseExact(a.OrderDate,"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) => endDate).ToList();
```

**Note:** Use res which will be filtered based on the date range you provide. Your start and end date should be in dd-MM-yyyy format.

Comment: i'm getting an error when i add the line st = DateTime.Parse(s.OrderDate)

Comment: @DibbaButt looks like you are replacing Convert.ToDateTime() with  st = DateTime.Parse(s.OrderDate) ? No. I will update my answer.

Comment: @DibbaButt were you able to try the solution?